# unexpected t_string error only on android web server apps

Tags: php, android, webserver

so I have a php script that compiles without errors on live hosters and xampp, but when I try run this script on Bit Web server for android or other similar web server apps for android I get unexpected t_string errors.

my current error is pointing to "foreach($priorityArr as $feature) {" I know there is no syntax errors with that line and my IDE agrees.

Here is the entire script I am trying to build

```
    <?php
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$resultArr = array(
    array('id'=>1234,'name'=>'prod1','feat1'=>2.3,'feat2'=>3.6,'feat3'=>4.5,'feat4'=>4.8),
    array('id'=>5678,'name'=>'prod2','feat1'=>3.4,'feat2'=>4.1,'feat3'=>2.3,'feat4'=>4.7),
    array('id'=>2143,'name'=>'prod3','feat1'=>1.2,'feat2'=>4.2,'feat3'=>3.7,'feat4'=>4.9),
    array('id'=>1243,'name'=>'prod4','feat1'=>3.7,'feat2'=>2.1,'feat3'=>3.8,'feat4'=>3.5),
);

$priorityArr = array('feat2','feat1','feat4','feat3');

$compArr = array();
$x=0;
foreach($priorityArr as $feature) { // feature
    $n=0;
    foreach($resultArr as $product) { // main product from db
        if(!array_key_exists($feature, $compArr)) {
            $compArr[$feature] = array('id' => $product['id'], 'score' => $product[$feature]);
        } else {
            $y=0;
            foreach($compArr as $score) {
                $score = $score['score'];
                //var_dump($score);
                echo $score.' = '.$product[$feature].' -- ';
                if($score < $product[$feature]) {
                    $compArr[$feature] = array('id' => $product['id'], 'score' => $product[$feature]);
                    //$compArr[$feature][$y][] = $product['id'];
                }
                $y++;
            }

        }
        $n++;
    }
    $x++;
}


print_r($compArr);

?>
```

Any ideas as to what I am doing wrong or why I am only getting this problem on my Android web servers?

Comment: That is the first line with a comment.  Try removing the comments or using other comment methods.

Comment: Errors like that (`unexpected t_string`), are usually associated with quotes. All I can come up with is to try and change `echo $score.' = '.$product[$feature].' -- ';` with `echo $score." = ".$product[$feature]." -- ";` or escaping the single quotes. Other than that, I'm stumped.

Comment: @Fred-ii-  I would say, they are usually associated with incompatible text encoding in the source file.  It happens to quotes more often because so many programs "helpfully" change them to "prettier" characters.  The source file may need to be saved with a different encoding.  I pointed to the comment on that line because I believe the double-slash is not being interpreted as a comment start, for whatever reason.

Comment: I will agree on that point. @spsc_tech

Comment: I never thought about the text encoding, I will look into that along with quotes sugestions and let you know my findings when I try it out. thanks a lot.